# jquery : access element inside an angular *ngIf directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to access an input element using jquery hidden inside an *ngIf directive. For a simple example :

```
...
export class ViewChannelScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

   someFunction() {
   ...
      doSomething($('#my-input'));
   ...
   }
}
...

<!-- and finally -->
<input id='my-input' />
```

The thing works great, until I decided to hide the component using *ngIf. Something like this..

```
...    
export class ViewChannelScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

   isInputVisible = false;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.isInputVisible = true;
      doSomething($('#my-input')); //unable to catch element
   }

}
...

<!-- and finally -->
<button (click)="showInputBox()">Enable</button>
<input *ngIf="isInputVisible" class='date-time-picker' />
```

I figured out that immediately after setting the `isInputVisible` value, jquery is unable to fetch the element. I verified the thing with a quick hack :

```
showInputBox() {
   this.isInputVisible = true;
   setTimeout(doSomething($('#my-input')), 100); //this works
}
```

Is there any neat way to ask jquery to wait for the element to be visible and callback?

Or any way to reference the input element directly in angular and convert it into jquery object within the function?

Comment: I dont think using jQuery inside an angular app is a good idea, you can do most of the stuff with Angular that you can with jQuery. If you want a reference to the element you can use the @ViewChild decorator: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild provided by Angular.

Comment: `ngIf is a directive`, When you use **ngIf** it will add and remove element from DOM. So it will take some time to add element again that why its working with `settimeout().` If you want to just hide element use `display : none` style, Like this : `[style.display]="isInputVisible ? 'block' : 'none'"` instead of '*ngIf="isInputVisible"' in your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore the part where you are using jquery inside angular and using an ID to reference the element ;) anyways, in your 2nd code example you are using `ngOnInit`. In this hook there are no template elements available yet. For that you have to go to the `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

But you cannot just change a view property inside that hook, this will give an expression has changed warning.

If you just want to use it in your `showInputBox` you can use the `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
constructor(readonly cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

showInputBox() {
   this.isInputVisible = true;
   this.cd.detectChanges();
   doSomething($('#my-input');
}
```

Or just use a `setTimeout` like you already did, but then without the 100ms:

```
showInputBox() {
   this.isInputVisible = true;
   setTimeout(() => doSomething($('#my-input'));
}
```

This makes sure it goes to the next change detection loop

Comment: While the answer works, I think you should develop more on the first paragraph and give him an Angular solution rather than a JQuery one !

Comment: @trichetriche I tried, but `doSomething` expects a `jQuery` object, and probably loads a library method from there. Not much I can rewrite to angular there.. But I agree with you, no jquery inside angular :)